# Is PIVOT the right way to concatenate and convert rows to columns?

Tags: sql-server

In MS SQL Server 2016

```sql
select 
    mdl_user.firstname + ' ' + mdl_user.lastname as studentname
    , mdl_quiz.name as quizname
    , mdl_quiz_attempts.attempt as attemptnumber
    , mdl_quiz_attempts.timefinish as attemptdate
    , mdl_quiz_attempts.sumgrades as attemptgrade
from mdl_quiz_attempts 
join mdl_quiz on mdl_quiz.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.quiz
join mdl_user on mdl_user.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.userid
order by mdl_user.id, mdl_quiz.name, mdl_quiz_attempts.attempt;
```

gives me the following output:

> ```
> studentname   quizname                    attemptnumber   attemptdate         attemptgrade
> Mariy Vickery Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 06:50    26
> Jan Le Roux   Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 08:15    36
> Jan Le Roux   Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 07:34    32
> Andrew Small  Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 10:34    30
> Andrew Small  Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 11:24    27
> Andrew Small  Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/30 12:15    32
> Deon Lenark   Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 10:22    29
> Deon Lenark   Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 11:05    35
> Chris Du Bill Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 10:25    34
> Chris Du Bill Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 08:06    34
> Craig Eben    Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 12:43    35
> Craig Eben    Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 11:36    28
> Craig Eben    Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/30 12:05    28
> Charm Grey    Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 08:33    34
> Charm Grey    Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 12:33    35
> Jaco Cloete   Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 09:04    32
> Dirk Schaan   Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 08:04    34
> Dirk Schaan   Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 09:03    11
> Dirk Schaan   Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/30 11:37    30
> Deon Grobler  Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 07:49    27
> Deon Grobler  Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/31 12:45    31
> Ester Shannah Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 10:32    36
> Ester Shannah Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 11:32    30
> Ester Shannah Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/30 12:21    35
> Eve Haywood   Fundamentals Assessment     1               2017/02/28 07:36    33
> Eve Haywood   Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 07:28    32
> Fred Bezzo    Income Tax Assessment       1               2017/03/30 08:22    30
> Fred Bezzo    Income Tax Assessment       2               2017/03/31 11:54    31
> ```

Each studentname has completed one or both of the two quizzes (quizname). Some students have attempted one or both quizzes two times (as indicated by the attemptnumber column).

I'd like to "pivot" the data so that all the results for each student is displayed in one row, like this:

```
=================================================================
studentname     Fundamentals Assessment     Income Tax Assessment
=================================================================
Mariy Vickery                               2017/03/30 06:50 - 26
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Jan Le Roux     2017/02/28 08:15 - 36       2017/03/30 07:34 - 32
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Andrew Small    2017/02/28 10:34 - 30       2017/03/30 11:24 - 27
                2017/03/30 12:15 - 32
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Deon Lenark     2017/02/28 10:22 - 29       2017/03/30 11:05 - 35
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Chris Du Bill   2017/02/28 10:25 - 34       2017/03/30 08:06 - 34
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Craig Eben      2017/02/28 12:43 - 35       2017/03/30 11:36 - 28
                                            2017/03/30 12:05 - 58
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Charm Grey      2017/02/28 08:33 - 34       2017/03/30 12:33 - 35
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Jaco Cloete     2017/03/30 09:04 - 32
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Dirk Schaan     2017/02/28 08:04 - 34       2017/03/30 09:03 - 11
                                            2017/03/30 11:37 - 30
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Deon Grobler                                2017/03/30 07:49 - 27
                                            2017/03/31 12:45 - 31
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Ester Shannah   2017/02/28 10:32 - 22       2017/03/30 11:32 - 30
                2017/02/28 15:20 - 36       2017/03/30 12:21 - 35
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Eve Haywood     2017/02/28 07:36 - 33       2017/03/30 07:28 - 32
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Fred Bezhout                                2017/03/30 08:22 - 30
                                            2017/03/31 11:54 - 31
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

But the PIVOT() function performs aggregations, which I don't want to do - I want to include ALL the grades/attempts for each studentname.

The following PIVOT() doesn't return what I want - it only returns one attemptnumber (because of the max(quiz_grade)
 aggregation) when there are multiple attempts. And it repeats the studentname on each row, which looks ugly:

```sql
select 
    * 
from (
    select 
        mdl_user.firstname + ' ' + mdl_user.lastname as fullname,
        mdl_quiz.name as quiz_name,  
        mdl_quiz_grades.grade as quiz_grade
    from mdl_quiz
    join mdl_quiz_grades on mdl_quiz.id = mdl_quiz_grades.quiz
    join mdl_course on mdl_course.id = mdl_quiz.course
    join mdl_user on mdl_user.id = mdl_quiz_grades.userid
) source
pivot ( 
    max(quiz_grade)
    for quiz_name in (
        [Fundamentals Assessment],
        [Income Tax Assessment]
    )
) as PIVT
order by fullname
```

So it looks like PIVOT() the not correct function to use here? How do I "pivot" the data AND concatenate the attemptdate and attemptgrade columns like my sample above shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try stuff and xml path like this:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(studentname VARCHAR(20),
      quizname VARCHAR(50),
      attemptnumber INT,
      attemptdate DATETIME,
      attemptgrade INT);


INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES
    ('Mariy Vickery', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 06:50', 26)
    , ('Jan Le Roux', 'Fundamentals Assessment', 1, '2017/02/28 08:15', 36) 
    , ('Jan Le Roux', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 07:34', 32) 
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Fundamentals Assessment', 1, '2017/02/28 10:34', 30) 
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 11:24', 27)
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Income Tax Assessment', 2, '2017/03/30 12:15', 32);

SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        studentname as fullname,
        quizname as quiz_name,  
        STUFF( (SELECT + '  ' + CAST(attemptdate AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' - ' 
                    + CAST(attemptgrade AS VARCHAR(3)) AS quiz_grade
                FROM @myTable si 
                WHERE si.studentname = so.studentname and si.quizname = so.quizname
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,''
        ) AS quiz_grade
    FROM @myTable so 
) SOURCE
PIVOT 
( 
    MAX(quiz_grade)
    FOR quiz_name IN ([Fundamentals Assessment],[Income Tax Assessment])
) AS PIVT
ORDER BY fullname
```

Comment: Thanks Raska. The SELECT in the stuff() function selects from "#student si" whereas the main SELECT selects from "#student so". Is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: Won't the max() call in "max(quiz_grade)" make the query return just one grade for each studentname in each quizname? I do want the query to return ALL the quiz_grade results for each student who has written the quizname more than once.

Comment: Lusidev, si and so are not typos...it's a kind of join on the table itself. Required to get correct stuff output! Since stuff is going to return your results in a single row for single user, max will not have any impact.

Comment: Thanks Raska. Now si and so makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(studentname VARCHAR(20),
      quizname VARCHAR(50),
      attemptnumber INT,
      attemptdate DATETIME,
      attemptgrade INT);
DECLARE @myTable1 TABLE(studentname VARCHAR(20),
      [Fundamentals Assessment] VARCHAR(MAX),
      [Income Tax Assessment] VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES
    ('Mariy Vickery', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 06:50', 26)
    , ('Jan Le Roux', 'Fundamentals Assessment', 1, '2017/02/28 08:15', 36) 
    , ('Jan Le Roux', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 07:34', 32) 
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Fundamentals Assessment', 1, '2017/02/28 10:34', 30) 
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 11:24', 27)
    , ('Andrew Small', 'Income Tax Assessment', 2, '2017/03/30 12:15', 32)
    , ('Deon Lenark', 'Fundamentals Assessment', 1, '2017/02/28 10:22', 35)
    , ('Deon Lenark', 'Income Tax Assessment', 1, '2017/03/30 11:05', 34);


INSERT INTO @myTable1
SELECT studentname, 
    MAX([Fundamentals Assessment]) [Fundamentals Assessment], 
    MAX([Income Tax Assessment]) [Income Tax Assessment]
FROM
(
    SELECT studentname, IIF([Fundamentals Assessment] IS NOT NULL, 
        CONCAT([Fundamentals Assessment],' - ' ,attemptgrade),NULL) 
            AS [Fundamentals Assessment],
        IIF([Income Tax Assessment] IS NOT NULL, 
        CONCAT([Income Tax Assessment],' - ' ,attemptgrade),NULL) 
            AS [Income Tax Assessment], attemptnumber
    FROM
    (
        SELECT studentname, 
         IIF(quizname = 'Fundamentals Assessment',attemptdate,NULL) 
                AS [Fundamentals Assessment]
            ,IIF(quizname = 'Income Tax Assessment',attemptdate,NULL) 
                AS [Income Tax Assessment]
            ,attemptgrade, attemptnumber
        FROM @myTable
    ) AS A
)B
GROUP BY studentname, attemptnumber
ORDER BY studentname, attemptnumber


SELECT DISTINCT studentname, E.[Fundamentals Assessment], D.[Income Tax Assessment] 
    FROM @myTable1 p1
   CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT [Income Tax Assessment] + '  ' 
        FROM @myTable1 p2
        WHERE p2.studentname = p1.studentname 
        ORDER BY [Income Tax Assessment] 
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    )  D ( [Income Tax Assessment] )
    CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT [Fundamentals Assessment] + '  '
        FROM @myTable1 p2
        WHERE p2.studentname = p1.studentname 
        ORDER BY [Fundamentals Assessment] 
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    )  E ( [Fundamentals Assessment] )
```

Comment: Thanks Tekca.  That really helps.

Where the student has attempted a 'quizname' quiz more than once (and thus has more than one result) your code returns two rows (one for each attempt) with the studentname repeated in the first column in all the ROWS. See the Andrew Small example.

Is it possible to combine the two date/results into one cell where the student has more than one date/result for a quizname so that all the results for each student are merged into one row? (So there will be only one row for Andrew Small with his two 'Income Tax Assessment' results merged into one cell.)

Comment: **Dynamic SQL** might be the best approach for this. You can also concatenate the columns using the **FOR XML** clause with **PATH** mode. A third option is to use the **CROSS APPLY** operator. The initial answer modified to use the **CROSS APPLY** option

Comment: @luisdev - Raska's response; it's a cleaner solution than mine. I have however modified it - slightly changed the STUFF function and added temp table data for testing. Give it a test

Answer (score 1):

If you need a dynamic version

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Distinct
               studentname 
              ,Item = quizname
              ,value = replace( Stuff((Select concat(format(attemptdate,''|yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm - ''),attemptgrade) From YourTable Where studentname=A.studentname and quizname=A.quizname For XML Path ('''')),1,1,'''') ,''|'',char(13))
         From  YourTable A
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(quizname) 
                                               From YourTable  
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
studentname     Fundamentals Assessment Income Tax Assessment
Andrew Small    2017/02/28 10:34 - 30   2017/03/30 11:24 - 27
                                        2017/03/30 12:15 - 32
Charm Grey      2017/02/28 08:33 - 34   2017/03/30 12:33 - 35
Chris Du Bill   2017/02/28 10:25 - 34   2017/03/30 08:06 - 34
Craig Eben      2017/02/28 12:43 - 35   2017/03/30 11:36 - 28
                                        2017/03/30 12:05 - 28
Deon Grobler    NULL                    2017/03/30 07:49 - 27
                                        2017/03/31 12:45 - 31
Deon Lenark     2017/02/28 10:22 - 29   2017/03/30 11:05 - 35
Dirk Schaan     2017/02/28 08:04 - 34   2017/03/30 09:03 - 11
                                        2017/03/30 11:37 - 30
Ester Shannah   2017/02/28 10:32 - 36   2017/03/30 11:32 - 30
                                        2017/03/30 12:21 - 35
Eve Haywood     2017/02/28 07:36 - 33   2017/03/30 07:28 - 32
Fred Bezzo      NULL                    2017/03/30 08:22 - 30
                                        2017/03/31 11:54 - 31
Jaco Cloete     NULL                    2017/03/30 09:04 - 32
Jan Le Roux     2017/02/28 08:15 - 36   2017/03/30 07:34 - 32
Mariy Vickery   NULL                    2017/03/30 06:50 - 26
```